# Craft 3 RC Upgrade killed the WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: craft3, wysiwyg

I just finished upgrading to Craft 3 RC and all text on the site is gone. The WYSIWYG Editor has been replaced with this message:

```
Unable to find component class 'craft\fields\RichText'.
```

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With RC1 the rich text editor was moved to a plugin. You can find the Redactor editor (the previous richtext field) in the plugin store along with a new CKEditor editor as well.

You can read about this in the docs, too: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#rich-text-fields

Comment: Issue fixed. I will go and read the docs, asap.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the Plugins Sections.

and install the plugin with the name **Redactor**[image: Redactor Plugin]

And everything will be back to normal.